# Least Squares Regression to Solve a Non-Linear System

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, algorithms

I'm trying to solve the following non-linear system;

$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2} + s(t_2-t_1) = \sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 + ( y-y_2)^2}$

$\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2} + s(t_3-t_2) = \sqrt{(x-x_3)^2 + ( y-y_3)^2}$

$\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2 + (y-y_3)^2} + s(t_1-t_3) = \sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + ( y-y_1)^2}$

For the unknowns, $x$ and $y$ (all other values are known, and constant).

I understand that the solution involves Least Squares Regression, and I understand the concept on an intuitive level, however I'm not sure how one would apply LSR to a *system* of equations, nor what I would do afterwards to obtain the unknowns.

Admittedly, this is something I know little about, so I'm looking for both an intuitive explanation and a more detailed "technical" explanation such that I can implement this.

If it is at all useful to know, I'm working with CERN's ROOT Data Analysis framework (see https://root.cern), in  C++.

Comment: How you get that system of equations? What has you thinking least squares will help you solve it?

Comment: @Dave Hi. This is a "standard" solution to the problem (i.e. what you'd find if you looked in some research papers, probably if you Googled it), which follows fairly intuitively/directly from the premises. Admittedly, I probably cannot provide an entirely satisfactory answer to your second question. Superficially, it seems reasonable since there is (in general) no exact solution to this system. Again, if you Google this or look at any research papers on this sort of thing, LSR is mentioned (and, in my case, more than a few math & physics profs. have also suggested this is the best path to take

Comment: @Dave )...but none elaborate. Someone suggested-- "You want to minimize the sum of the squares of the errors. And for that you get two equations, for the partial derivatives both being 0. The expression is messy, but 2 equations in 2 variables is then solvable.", without further elaboration.... I too am not entirely sure precisely how LSR would apply here, which is part of the reason for this post.

Comment: Because you haven't disclosed the application, you have made it difficult for your readers to recognize the inherent simplicity of the problem or to suggest effective solutions.  I strongly recommend that you provide that context in the question itself.  For an example of some of the issues as discussed in closely related situation see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/40678/664 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2895/664. From what I can tell, your application also accounts for the times that signals arrive.